# Runas savecred resets after each login

Tags: cmd, runas

I have a program set to launch automatically via a runas savecred command and would like to make it so that it doesn't prompt me for the password for each login

On Windows 10, I have a command shortcut in startup to launch a program as a different user than I am logging into the computer with.  With the runas savecred switch, it still prompts for the password at each login in the commmand prompt

C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME "mmc %windir%\system32\dsa.msc"

I would like for it to simply launch the application every time I log into windows.  It currently prompts me for the password when the command runs.  Does the savecred credentials get deleted when you log out of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but try adding /persistent:yes